dhtmlxgrid not working during pagination and during edit
I have a DHTMLX grid with pagination enabled. Grid have checkbox
During edit when I am trying to set checkbox value in 2nd / 3rd page of grid it's not working.
Grid.cells(rowID, 0).setValue(1);
Even Grid.doesRowExist(rowID), giving error
But updating value in first page it's working fine.
Any Idea
Grid.cells(rowID, 0).setValue(1)

Please, make sure you are not using dynamic loading of data in your grid.
https://docs.dhtmlx.com/grid__dynamic_loading.html
As in this case the data gets loaded to the client side and to the grid by portions according to the current view. So not all the data is available and you are not able to operate with it until it is loaded.
